# Creating custom "smart" brackets

Tags: macros, lyx, templates

I'm trying to add some kind of macro/new command to my LyX template in which typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> or just using the command `\floor` would create a "smart" floor brackets, just like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> create normal brackets.

Is that possible?